# Getting 1341M in SPOJ?

Tags: java, memory

I am getting 1341 Memory used on this simple program on SPOJ. I want to reduce it to 2 to 3M. How can I improve the code. Where I am using more memory. I have given program bwlow:

```
 import java.util.*;
 import java.lang.*;
 import java.io.*;

 class Test
 {
  public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    String str=new String();
    String str1[]=new String[10];
    int len;
    int t=sc.nextInt();
    for(int i=0;i<t;i++)
    {
        str=sc.next();
        str1=str.split("");
        len=str.length()/2;
        for(int j=0;j<len;j++)
        {
            if(j%2==0)
            {
                System.out.print(str1[j]);
            }
        }
    System.out.println();

    }
}
}
```

Comment: it's Java after all - just loading the system libs puts you way beyound the 2 to 3 mb memory target you have. You can try to specify -Xmx memory options on start and see what is absolute minimum for your code to run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't convert String `str` to the String array `str1` to access single characters of  `str`. Instead use

```
if (j%2 == 0)
   System.out.print(str.charAt(j));
```

Comment: Thank you.But after changing it too, it's taking 1341M.

Comment: I got that I have instantiated object str, which was not required. Now after changing it's giving 315M.

Comment: @5extremers you do you measure memory?

Comment: @5extremers now get rid of variable `str1` too, you don't need it